# Playwright force click on hidden element does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I am using Playwright for end to end testing. One of the scenario involves checking the content of a pdf displayed in a PDFviewer window, for which download button have been hidden for the end user. Checking the pdf content involves downloading it, thus I used
the `force` option mentionned by Playwright documentation :
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click

The implementation used is the following :

```js
innerFrameContent.click("//button[contains(@id, 'secondaryDownload')]", { force: true })
```

(the xpath is correct, I checked within Chrome browser and managed to click on the element through the console )

Unfortunatly, I get the following exception log from Playwright :

```
frame.click: Element is not visible
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "//button[contains(@id, 'secondaryDownload')]"
  selector resolved to hidden <button tabindex="54" title="Download" id="secondaryDown…>…</button>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
    forcing action
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
============================================================
...
```

Comment: You can also perform **soft programming click** on hidden or overlapping elements. See my answer below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251842

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting `force` to true means that you want to bypass the actionability check. It doesn't mean that the `click` will work.
In this case, if `force` would have been set to `false`, the action would have failed due to a timeout, it would have waited for the element to be visible.
With `force` in true, you don't get a timeout, but the click will fail because you can't click an invisible element.

You might need to find another way to perform the action, javascript maybe?

Comment: I ended doing as you said, with javacript - with playwright api using the function `evaluate` on my button `ElementHandle`

Comment: @AugBar Can you show an example of your fix. I am looking at the playwright docs, just wondering if you can help me, I have the same issue.

Comment: I did something like :
`const unvisibleButton = await browser.page.$(unvisibleButtonPath); unvisibleButton.evaluate((node: HTMLElement) => {node.click()})`

Answer (score 1):

Click in Playwright has default actionability checks such as Action,Attached,Visible,Stable,Receives Events,Enabled,Editable.

Even using force=true, doesn’t skip some of these. So better don’t use click, instead use dispatchEvent.
Example => `page.getByTestId('#id').dispatchEvent("click");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform an **soft programming click**:

```
page.$eval(selector, (element) => element.click())
```

> Soft Programmatic click will work even if the element is invisible,
> has zero size, is behind another element or is otherwise not
> interactable.