# Unable to click checkbox ::before using playwright

Tags: playwright

I am using playwright to click on checkbox . The checkbox gets highlighted only when I hover over ':before'.  I used

```
xpath "//*[@id="provision-case-sku-selection"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/label/span"
```

it throws error

```
selector resolved to hidden <span class="label__text checkbox__text"></span>
attempting click action
waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
element is not visible - waiting...
```

Attaching image of the DOM here
"
[image: HTML]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playwright force click on hidden element does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124342/playwright-force-click-on-hidden-element-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo elements cannot be accessed via Javascript, they are not in the DOM. There is no way to programmatically click a pseudo element.

Pseudo elements are generated content via the CSS rendering engine of the browser.

Try to click the `span` element instead and see what happens.

Edit: By the looks of it your tool is intelligent enough to know it cannot access `::before`, so it tries to click the hosting `span` element already. Some check seems to think the element is not visible, thus you get:

```
selector resolved to hidden <span class="label__text checkbox__text"></span>
attempting click action
waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
element is not visible - waiting...
```

Comment: is there any way to use it while automation? I am stuck and not able to proceed

Comment: Try to click the `span` element instead and see what happens.

Comment: clicking on span gives same error

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124342/playwright-force-click-on-hidden-element-does-not-work and https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle

Comment: await page.$eval('locator', elem => elem.click()); to run the click inside the webpage          ........This finally worked

Comment: @tannushreesinha  can you post working code here. I am also facing same issue. Can you help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110874/how-click-checkbox-with-css-locator-after-using-playwright?noredirect=1#comment127413322_72110874

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but working in most cases:

1. Find an element that is close and in DOM. Often, label next to it.
2. Use the `boundingBox()` method to get the `x, y, width, height` of the element. (note that x/y is top left, and y is increasing downward)
3. Using these values, make the center x/y of the element that you want to click.
4. Use `await page.mouse.click(x, y)` to click.

```
async checkAgreeBox() {
    const labelLocator = this.page.getByText('I agree ... Terms');
    const labelBounds = await labelLocator.boundingBox();
    expect(labelBounds).toBeTruthy();

    const bounds = labelBounds!;
    const clickX = bounds.x - bounds.height;
    const clickY = bounds.y + bounds.height / 2;
    await this.page.mouse.click(clickX, clickY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not the correct solution for the checkbox click, **but this can help you to locate the text from the element ***::before*****

Here we can find an explanation about **::before** as a CSS pseudo-element

[MSDN pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

If we are expecting to access this element as any other element inside the HTML document it will fail; this pseudo-code works dynamically and set the text for the element in a different load period, for this reason, we need some Playwright Javascript interface that saves us from this headache!!.

We can use the Browser console to verify if ***getComputedStyle*** retrieves the text that is stored in the attribute ***.content*** as:

> getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.header-app-name'),'::before').content

Once the expected text is shown, continue to integrate into the playwright as:

> const result = await page.$eval('.header-app-name', e => getComputedStyle(e, '::before').content);
> expect(result).toBe('Hellow ::before world');

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I've got was executing a JS function with page.evaluate.

In your case the solution will be like this:

```
await page.evaluate("document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox').click()");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77388891/23116460) and it worked, so I did something like

```
await page.locator('#accept-terms').dispatchEvent("click");
```