# How click checkbox with CSS locator ::after using playwright

Tags: javascript, automation, playwright, playwright-test

I have to click checkbox for term & conditions. I have used  `.click()` and `.check` in my code. But when I am running the code, it's clicking on the terms & conditions and it's redirecting to another page. can you suggest any help.
below is my html
[image]

When I hover mouse to `::before` and `::after` checkbox is highlighting.
[image]

`await this.page.locator('#lb-confirm').click()`

`await this.page.locator('#lb-confirm').check`

Edit: I have tried with jquery in console and able to click checkbox.
`$('#dr-cb-confirm').trigger('click')`
with above code, how can I convert to playwright code.
I have tried with below code
 `await page.locator(''#dr-cb-confirm').click()` .. Playwright was tried to click and but not finally it was exited from execution.

Comment: Please post your code. Images don't count as code, post it at text.

Comment: Shouldn't you click on `#dr-cb-confirm` ?

Comment: @hardkoded,   Yes, I have used but ``#dr-cb-confirm``  but no use. When I hover to ::after or ::before checkbox is highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Since I was unable to click checkbox, I have jQuery to click the checkbox `$('#dr-cb-confirm').trigger('click')` . When I want to call the jQuery command in playwright I have installed jQuery library using `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery`.
Then I have updated my code with jQuery
`await this.page.evaluate(() => $('#dr-cb-confirm').trigger('click'))`